# Timing out tests in a Perl test harness

Tags: perl, tap-harness

How could I time out hanging tests in a Perl test harness?

I tried using the `Test::Timer` module, but I can't seem to make it link up nicely with the `TAP::Harness` in order to have an embedded timeout function for each test. Plus, I don't want to test if a bit of code takes `x` time to complete, I just want to run my tests and timeout in case they hung for any reason.

Answer (score 4):

There was [a similar question on PerlMonks](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=1091994) recently.

Install [Time::Limit](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Limit).

This module will allow you to set time limits for individual test files:

```
use Test::More;
use Time::Limit "30";   # 30 seconds, quote marks are necessary!
```

Or set an overall time limit for running the entire test suite:

```
prove -MTime::Limit=120 t/*.t
```

If you're using `forkprove` instead of `prove`, then you need the time limiter to kill the entire process group:

```
forkprove -MTime::Limit=-group,120 t/*.t
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work for me. I should mention I'm trying to use it on a windows machine. What I've got so far is `sub test_with_timeout {
 my $current_test=shift || die "Must provide a test";
 my $harness = shift || die "Must provide a harness";
 my $timeout=shift || -1;

 $SIG{ALRM} = sub {
 print "Timeout after $timeout seconds\n";
 die;
 };
# print  "Timeout is $timeout seconds\n\n";
 alarm($timeout);
 my $result=$harness->runtests($current_test);
 alarm(0);
 return $result;


}`